# Where is the best place to hunt bobcats?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

I absolutely for the life of me cannot find these anywhere.  The only area that my hunting guide even thinks they show up in is the one with the lighthouse (the name escapes me at the moment) but I've been over every inch of it and not found a single one past that first one.  Is there a trick to this or a specific spot where they like to live?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the far northwest.  There is a fort up there, and a Hunting Cabin.  Go north from the fort or west from the cabin.  There will also be a sidequest to go hunt down a unique bobcat up that way, but I found it to be teeming even before that.

Comment: Up where the sasquatch mission was?  I hung out up there for a while when I did that because I hadn't really been on that side of the map at all but I didn't see a one...will have to check again.

Comment: Try northeast of the Sasquatch hideout.  There is an area with a small military encampment on top of some rocks.  This area seems to be filled with bobcats.

Answer (score 1):

I found them to be thick in the way up in the hills on the "great Piece Hills" side of the boarder with "diamond Basin".

Comment: This is where I originally looked and never found any past the first, actually. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can find this on the west of great piece hills.

Answer (score 0):

Go straight north from the fort (Fort at top west Corner) you must swim across the lake while heading north. when you are at the other side, there is huge cliff wall, just follow that west. until you come to a small civillian camp. In that area there are 3 bobcats.

Comment: Could someone confirm wether the camp is east or west?

Comment: @Timelord64: I'm inclined to decline the edit based on "significantly changing intent," and then if it's wrong, it'll be downvoted appropriately.